# JAXB - PascalCase Wrapper for Class Collection

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-rs

I am writing a JAX-RS using JAXB for marshaling my objects. I have a simple object, `NameValuePair` that I want to send across in PascalCase. Everything works, except it is wrapped in a camelCase wrapper, `<nameValuePairs>`.

This is my class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "NameValuePair")
public class NameValuePair implements Serializable {

    private String name = null;
    private String value = null;

    public NameValuePair( String name, String value ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Value")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This is how it's used:

```
public Response getNameValuePairs() {
    NameValuePair[] nameValuePairs;
    try {
        nameValuePairs = manager.getNameValuePairs();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .build();
    }

    return Response
            .status(Response.Status.OK)
            .entity(nameValuePairs)
            .build();
}
```

However, the XML returned looks like this:

```
<nameValuePairs>
    <NameValuePair>
        <Name>A Name</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </NameValuePair>
    <NameValuePair>
        <Name>Another Name</Name>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </NameValuePair>
</nameValuePairs>
```

How can I change `<nameValuePairs>` to `<NameValuePairs>` to match with the rest of the schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the array name is used for the root node of your XML. The easiest way to me, seems to wrap your entities in an List:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="NameValuePairs")
public class NameValuePairs {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
}
```

And return:

```
public Response getNameValuePairs() {
    return Response
        .entity(new NameValuePairs(...))
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. For some reason I have to make the `List<T>` public though instead of using a getter or I got an exception. I also had to add the `@XmlElement` annotation to the `List<T>`.